How can I implement a function to call any templated lambda function?
I have a value_t to wrap a value as a type:
template <auto _v>
struct value_t { static constexpr auto value = _v; };

I can use take_off to extract the type and value:
template <typename T>
struct take_off { using magic = T; };
template <auto _v>
struct take_off<value_t<_v>> { static constexpr auto magic = _v; };

Now I want to call any lambda function with any template arguments and function arguments by calling invoke(c++20 or 23):
auto test_fn = []<typename T, typename T2, T... Vs>(int a, int b){
    (..., (std::cout << (T2)Vs << std::endl));
    std::cout << a << b << std::endl;
};

// template <typename...>
// auto invoke(test_fn, ...)

invoke<int, double, value_t<1>, value_t<2>, value_t<5>>(test_fn, 1, 2);

My implementation of invoke is:
template <typename... Ts>
decltype(auto) invoke(auto _fn, auto... _args) {
    return _fn.template operator()<take_off<Ts>::magic...>(_args...);
}

It seems to works well on the MSVC, due to msvc's extended standard.
However, an error has occurred when it is compiled by clang:
error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name `take_off<Ts>::magic`

invoke will no longer work for auto template arguments if I use typename take_off<Ts>::magic instead.
So is there any way to implement this invoke?
For example, if we limit template parameters to a maximum of N, here we need 8.
A bad implementation would be to enumerate all cases by judging the type or value flag of each magic and rounding null flag to 8, which would require implementing 3^8 functions.
template <>
auto invoke_impl<t, t, v, v, v, null, null, null> {...}

Is there a way to simplify this process or is there another easier way to do it?

"it works well on the MSVC". With correct flags to make it standard compliant, it fails too :) Demo.

I haven't constrained the compile flags, so msvc will optimize my code in its way, but in fact the syntax is not up to standard :(

Looks like your question ultimately is "how to write a function like template<magic...> f() {} that accepts both type and non-type template arguments." I suppose this is impossible in current C++. You have to split your args in two chunks (one for types and one for non-types).
